# How to locate an element as per the HTML provided through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click a 'next' button with Selenium in Python, which source code is:

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
            <button id="experiment-method-previous" type="button" class="btn btn-dark pull-left" ng-click="navigate('run',$event)">Previous</button>
            <button id="experiment-method-next" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="navigate('export',$event)">Next</button>
        </div>
```

I use the line:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('experiment-method-next')
```

but I get this error:

```
Unable to locate element: [id="experiment-method-next"]
```

Same for

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-primary pull-right')
Unable to locate element: .btn btn-primary pull-right
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it make any difference that the final HTML comes after these lines of code (where basically I perform a double click on a previous button)? text = driver.find_element_by_id("5c87b90f-dd40-4c5e-9e1f-3a926ee77ecb-icon")
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.double_click(text).perform(). The final HTML opens on a different tab in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Next** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right#experiment-method-next"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary pull-right' and @id='experiment-method-next']"))).click()
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: for the CSS_SELECTOR: 
  File "<ipython-input-1-dde5b3959757>", line 59, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right#experiment-method-next"))).click()

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException

Comment: Hmmm, ipython issues. How about the xpath?

Comment: and the same for the XPATH

Comment: _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.

Answer (score 1):

I think your elememnt is inside `frame/iframe`. To be able to interact with elements inside `frame/iframe` you have to switch to it's content like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//path_to_frame")))
```

then you can locate your element and interact with it:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "experiment-method-next"))).click()
```

and when you are done with content inside `frame`, you have to switch back to default content:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

***Note:*** you have to do some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

***PS:*** if your elements is not inside frame, then just use `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "experiment-method-next"))).click()
```

this will wait at least 10 seconds until element will be clickable and the clicks on it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So far it's not working: a) for outside an iframe: `WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "experiment-method-next"))).click()` gives  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException.

Comment: And for the iframe, I am trying to find where is in and what I find before the source code I initially entered is this <iframe id="invisible" style="display:none;"></iframe>
  <iframe id="frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function clickTree(assetId,assetName) {
                //$scope.selectedValueTree = dataItem.assetId;
                console.log("dataitem "+assetId+" name:"+assetName);
                $("#hiddenAssetId").text(assetId);
                
            }
  </script>
  

  ...

Comment: can you provide a link to website?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot; it's not public.

Comment: Are there any other iframes or frames on the website?

Comment: If i do:  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe"), I get these 4: [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="ecee255f-95b8-2243-8cf3-19419faa455f", element="3abb1673-309d-8a40-b582-943450d1d1f3")>, ... Is this correct?

Comment: I would find them in dev tools. In the browser in dev tools by pressing `F12` then in the elements menu you will find the whole HTML. Click on the of  elements there and press `Ctrl + f`. You will see that search panel will appear. There you can type `//iframe` and all iframe elements will be located. Go througth them and check if your element is inside of iframe. Also check the same for ``//frame`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176104/discussion-between-user26872-and-andrei-suvorkov).

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to kill first any previous windows my application opens and switch to the latest one:

```
current_window = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(current_window)
```

Now, the Next Button can be clicked as follows:
`driver.find_element_by_id('experiment-method-next').click`()

Many thanks to the users *Andrei Suvorkov* and *DebanjanB* for their help.